# No video on built-in display after installing 14.04

Tags: 14.04, video, display, resolution, screen

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus N53TA notebook, but after the first reboot I got no video on the built-in display, although through the hdmi port everything works fine.

If I change the built-in display resolution (through a second monitor), the display turns on, and even if I change the resolution back to what it was, it keeps working fine (until the next reboot).

Other workaround I found is to deactivate and reactivate the built-in display on Ubuntu display settings, but again, it only works until the next reboot.

The problem doesn't happen when I run Ubuntu live cd.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could install arandr.
2. Use arandr to set up your screen.
3. Then save the screen configuration to a script.
4. Create a new Application Autostart item and copy the command from the script there or you could set the script to run at startup.

Answer (score -1):

If you see the purple screen on startup (if not press, <kbd>Esc</kbd> before Ubuntu starts):

1. Select Advanced Options.
2. Select Recovery Mode.
3. Select FailsafeX.
4. Click yes until you get back to continue with normal startup.

Your PC will hopefully start now. Then:

1. Select Programs and find Software and Updates.
2. Click Additional Drivers.
3. In the Additional Drivers dialog, select and install the display driver for your PC.

After that, restart, and everything should hopefully be in order.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I've edited this to make it clearer. But even before the edit, this post was a sequence of instructions intended to solve the problem--so it was an answer, not a comment. Even when an answer has serious quality problems or provides only a partial solution, [we have a rather strong community consensus that it is *even less appropriate* to post it as a comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281). While it's easy to do by accident via review (and I'm definitely not trying to single you out), I recommend against advising newcomers that half-answers should be posted as comments.